# Unique random number sampling with Numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to create a 10,000 x 50 array in which each row contains an ascending series of random numbers between 1 and 365, like so:

```
[[  4  11  14 ..., 355 360 364]
 [  2  13  15 ..., 356 361 361]
 [  4  12  18 ..., 356 361 365]
 ..., 
 [  6   9  17 ..., 356 362 364]
 [  1  10  19 ..., 352 357 360]
 [  1   9  17 ..., 356 358 364]]
```

The only way I've figured out to do this is by way of an iterator:

```
sample_dates = np.array([np.sort(np.random.choice(365, 50, replace=False)) for _ in range(10000)])
```

which works, but is pretty slow (~0.33 seconds to run) and I'm going to be doing this thousands of times). Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

EDIT: From what I can tell, the most expensive part of this solution is the iteration and 10k individual calls to np.random.choice, not the sorting

Comment: What are you going to use this for?

Comment: I'd suggest you a faster approach, but I don't want to add it as an answer because I don't know the programming language: what about generating a first random number at the beginning of the row, then for the nth element generate another random number and add it to the previous one. You get a sorted row of random numbers. To meet your interval requirements, use random numbers from 1 to 365/50

Answer (score 2):

The following solution does not use sort:

```
l = np.array([True]*50 + [False]*315)
total = np.arange(1,366)
sample_dates = np.array([total[np.random.permutation(l)] for _ in range(10000)])
```

Hence it seems to be faster than the other suggested solutions (takes 0.44 seconds on my computer versus 0.77 for "Nils Werner"'s solution. The OP's solution took 0.81 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

Considering the shapes of the arrays, I thought iterating on columns might provide some improvement. So my idea was to generate 10k numbers - with replacement. Then, on a loop, generate another 10k numbers and check for row-wise duplicates. If there are any, eliminate those and generate that many random numbers. This is also called hit and miss algorithm, if I remember correctly.

Here's the working code:

```
arr = np.random.choice(365, 10000)
for i in range(49):
    arr2 = np.random.choice(365, 10000)
    comp = (arr2 == arr)
    while comp.any():
        duplicate = comp if i==0 else comp.any(axis=0)
        arr2[duplicate] = np.random.choice(365, duplicate.sum())
        comp = (arr2 == arr)
    arr = np.vstack([arr, arr2])
arr = arr.T
arr.sort(axis=1)
```

This takes 93.4ms to complete. Your attempt takes 590ms on my computer so it provides ~6x improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trick with [`np.argpartition/np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).

The idea is -

- Get a random array of floats of shape `(10000,365)`, perform `argsort` on it along each row. This would give us unique indices, thus simulating the `replace=False` criteria as used with `np.random.choice`.
- Slice out the first `50` columns for each row.
- Finally, a sort along each row does the job of having a sorted data.

Now, we could further boost the performance with [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to partition along each row with `k=50`.

Thus, we would have a vectorized solution, like so -

```
np.sort(np.random.rand(10000,365).argpartition(50,axis=1)[:,:50])
```

Let's verify the uniformity of output data

```
In [209]: out = np.sort(np.random.rand(10000,365).argpartition(50,axis=1)[:,:50])

In [210]: count = np.bincount(out.ravel(), minlength=365)

In [211]: print count.min(), count.max()
1277 1466
```

Seems pretty uniform! Let's get to the main business, which is getting the performance numbers.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# Original approach
def org_app():
    return np.array([np.sort(np.random.choice(365, 50, replace=False)) for _ in range(10000)])

# @Nils Werner's soln
def sort_random_choice():
    return np.sort([np.random.choice(365, 50, replace=False) for _ in range(10000)], axis=1)

# @Miriam Farber's soln
def random_permute():
    l = np.array([True]*50 + [False]*315)
    total = np.arange(1,366)
    return np.array([total[np.random.permutation(l)] for _ in range(10000)])

# Proposed in this post
def argpartition_sort(nrows=10000, maxc=365, ncols=50):
    return np.sort(np.random.rand(nrows,maxc).argpartition(ncols,axis=1)[:,:ncols])

# @ayhan's soln
def while_loop():
    arr = np.random.choice(365, 10000)
    for i in range(49):
        arr2 = np.random.choice(365, 10000)
        comp = (arr2 == arr)
        while comp.any():
            duplicate = comp if i==0 else comp.any(axis=0)
            arr2[duplicate] = np.random.choice(365, duplicate.sum())
            comp = (arr2 == arr)
        arr = np.vstack([arr, arr2])
    arr = arr.T
    arr.sort(axis=1)
    return arr
```

Timings -

```
In [44]: %timeit org_app()
    ...: %timeit sort_random_choice()
    ...: %timeit random_permute()
    ...: %timeit argpartition_sort()
    ...: %timeit while_loop()
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 258 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 232 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 79.9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 58.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible optimization is to vectorize `sort` by putting it outside the loop:

```
sample_dates = np.sort([np.random.choice(365, 50, replace=False) for _ in range(10000)], axis=1)
```